# How to display columns that start with 0 and sum values in output string? AWK

Tags: awk

There is a file with 3 columns. Display sum of second and third number from each string if first number of the columns is 0.

```
1,2,3
3,4,5
0,1,2
0,0,7
```

Result:

```
3
7
```

I am trying this but for some reason I receive two 0 as a result:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^0/ {print $2 + $3}' zadanie.csv
```

Comment: missing the delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your file is comma separated you need to provide awk value of input field separator which is comma in this case.

```
awk -F, '$1 ~/^0/ {print $2+$3}' foo
3
7
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Is there any way to use regex in this script? In your solution there is a problem. If there is number 10 at first column script will think that it is actually 0 and it will include that string in next action which is wrong.

Comment: @znaczus ,  it will not not consider 10 as true. Here awk is searching for rows which starts with 0 , not rows which contains zero. so it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider the case where the first number IS zero (and not just starts with zero for cases like 03 or 05) then try this-

```
awk -F "," '$1==0 {print $2+$3}' file
```

This will only match columns where the first number is equal to zero.

Comment: first field starts with 0 not equal to zero, you may want to update.

Comment: @soFan If that's the case then your answer is already perfect. Let me just sneakily expand the scope of mine.

Comment: `awk '{if ($1==0) print $2+$3}'` can be simplified in something more idiomatic like `awk '$1==0 {print $2+$3}'` or even `awk '!$1{print $2+$3}'`.

Comment: @fedorqui, much more concise, thank you! I'll remember this. Edited the answer.